# Plot explicit cdf over ecdf

Tags: r, explicit, ecdf

I have some data and I just plotted the empirical cumulative distribution using `Ecdf`  like this:

```
Ecdf(data)
```

Now, I tried to adjust the parameters (lambda, mu, sigma) for a mixture of two normals to this data, and now I would like to plot the cdf of this model using and explicit function over the plot created by `Ecdf`, is there any way to do this or I just have to simulate data so then I can use again `Ecdf`?

The explicit function, just to illustrate is something like:

```
ipc_values_EM$lambda[1] * dnorm(x, ipc_values_EM$mu[1], ipc_values_EM$sigma[1]) 
+
ipc_values_EM$lambda[2] * dnorm(x, ipc_values_EM$mu[2], ipc_values_EM$sigma[2])
```

(as you can note, is the mixture of two normals different mu's and different sigmas)

Comment: This is more of a stats question but you could easily define a function which is the cdf of the mixture.  You would just replace the dnorm by pnorm in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried it and it worked perfectly :-) (I'll try to post any question like that to the stats forum next time).